# About definition for terms of audio codec

Tags: audio, audio-streaming, audio-recording, codec, pcm

When I was studying `Cocoa Audio Queue` document, I met several terms in audio codec. There are defined in a structure named [AudioStreamBasicDescription](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/CoreAudioDataTypesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/AudioStreamBasicDescription).

Here are the terms: 
1. Sample rate
2. Packet
3. Frame
4. Channel

I known about `sample rate` and `channel`. How I was confused by the other two. What do the other two terms mean?

Also you can answer this question by example. For example, I have an dual-channel PCM-16 source with a sample rate 44.1kHz, which means there are 2*44100 = 88200 Bytes PCM data per second. But how about `packet` and `frame`?

Thank you at advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are already familiar with the sample rate defintion. 
The sampling frequency or sampling rate, fs, is defined as the number of samples obtained in one second (samples per second), thus fs = 1/T.
So for a sampling rate of 44100 Hz, you have 44100 samples per second (per audio channel).

The number of frames per second in video is a similar concept to the number of samples per second in audio. Frames for our eyes, samples for our ears. Additional infos [here](http://learningcenter.berklee.edu/blog/sample-rate-explained).

If you have 16 bits depth stereo PCM it means you have 16*44100*2 = 1411200 bits per second => ~ 172 kB per second => around 10 MB per minute.

To the definition in [reworded terms](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-10-12-obtaining-and-interpreting-audio-data.html) from Apple:

```
Sample: a single number representing the value of one audio channel at one point in time.
Frame: a group of one or more samples, with one sample for each channel, representing the audio on all channels at a single point on time.
Packet: a group of one or more frames, representing the audio format's smallest encoding unit, and the audio for all channels across a short amount of time.
```

As you can see there is a subtle difference between audio and video frame notions. In one second you have for stereo audio at 44.1 kHz: 88200 samples and thus 44100 frames.

Compressed format like MP3 and AAC pack multiple frames in packets (these packets can then be written in MP4 file for example where they could be efficiently interleaved with video content). You understand that dealing with large packets helps to identify bits patterns for better coding efficiency.

> MP3, for example, uses packets of 1152 frames, which are the basic atomic unit of an MP3 stream. PCM audio is just a series of samples, so it can be divided down to the individual frame, and it really has no packet size at all.

For AAC you can have 1024 (or 960) frames per packet. This is described in the Apple document you pointed at:

> The number of frames in a packet of audio data. For uncompressed audio, the value is 1. For variable bit-rate formats, the value is a larger fixed number, such as 1024 for AAC. For formats with a variable number of frames per packet, such as Ogg Vorbis, set this field to 0.

In MPEG-based file format a packet is referred to as a *data* frame (not to be 
mingled with the previous audio frame notion). See Brad comment for more information on the subject.

Comment: +1, but your point about ears needing much higher sample rate than eyes isn't entirely correct.  When we encode audio with PCM, we're in the time domain, sampling pressure levels often enough to reproduce a frequency.  When looking at an image we are in the frequency domain, where colors are reproduced.  If we did images in the time domain, we would be sampling the photons.  Now some audio codecs work with audio in the frequency domain (such as MP3), and it isn't uncommon to have 1152 samples (@44.1kHz) encoded in a frame giving you a frequency domain sample rate of ~40fps for audio.

Comment: @Brad interesting comment. As I get to what you say if I look at a sample [MP4 file](http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4) with H264/AAC - stsz box - I see a sampleCount of 2185 for audio and 1116 for video. For video 1 sampleCount item = 1 video frame (fps 23.976). If I stick to what your saying I have 2185 "audio frames" each with 1024 samples as: 2185 ("audio frames") * 1024 (samples in one frame) = 48000 (sample rate) * 46.613 (duration in seconds). But would that not defeat the above definition of frame (which I understand was 1 frame = n samples where n is the number of channels)?

Comment: The term "frame" is a bit generic and has a few meanings.  You are correct that a PCM frame is a single sample for each channel.  In stereo at 44.1kHz, there are 44,100 frames per second, with a total of 88,200 samples per second (one for each channel).  For MPEG, a single *data* frame contains the data needed to decode to a fixed set of PCM frames for what is effectively a fixed amount of time.  That frame is usually 26ms long in time.  More info:  http://www.mp3-converter.com/mp3codec/frames.htm

Comment: thanks for the input - things are clear in my head now - I have improved my answer based on your comment.

Comment: Wonderful! Not only for the answer, but also for the discussion you left. Thank you all!